# need an example of the formula needed to solve this issue.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Need to find the formula that will give me the perpendicular point of intersection to a given line segment.

So my segment points [A = (3,5,1),B=(6,2,1)] The point of which I need to find the perpendicular intersection with respect to line segment AB is K=(4,1,2)... How would I get a result that would stay true regardless of change to the vector? Please include notes, any help is welcome.

Also not super smart so no crazy symbols. I need stuff broken down really hard. x) sorry if I'm asking a bit much but this is a place for questions.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I tried to just use the Pythagorean theorem but it doesn't work as I'd thought it would since the point isn't in respect to the Z of the point.

Answer (score 0):

$A=(3,5,1)\quad B=(6,2,1)\quad C=(4,1,2)\quad M=(x,y,z)$

$M$ belong to line $(AB)$ means $\vec{AM}=t\vec{AB}$

$(CM)\perp(AB)$ means that the scalar product is zero $\vec{CM}\cdot\vec{AB}=0$

So you get $(\vec{CA}+\vec{AM})\cdot\vec{AB}=0\iff t=\dfrac{\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{AB}}{AB\ ^2}$

And finally, find $M=A+t\vec{AB}$

Answer (score 0):

First let's find the direction vector for line $AB$: $\vec d=(3-6,5-2,1-1)=(-3,3,0)$. Vector $\vec p(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to vector $\vec d$ if $\vec d \cdot \vec p=0$. Thus, $-3a + 3b=0$ or $a=b$ We can pick $a=1$. Now we need perpendicular to go thru a point $P(4,1,2)$. We have $x-4=y-1$ as our perpendicular.

Comment: this is also appreciated.  <3